# How can I paint an object and make it stay through if statements. I have tried creating a boolean but don't know how to keep it true

Tags: java, jframe, mouseevent, bufferedimage

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    RocketLaunch r = new RocketLaunch(0,0,0,0,0);
    Warehouse w = new Warehouse (100,100,500,500,this);
    Selector s = new Selector(this, w);
    Nose n = new Nose();



    public Main() {



        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                s.mousePressed(me);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                s.mouseReleased(me);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                s.mouseClicked(me);
            }


        });

        setFocusable(true);


    }



    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paint(g2d);
        //r.paint(g2d);
        w.paint(g2d);
        s.paint(g2d);
        n.paint(g2d);

    }


    public void move() {
        //r.move();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rocket");
        Main panel = new Main();
        frame.add(panel);

        //frame.setSize(1020, 640);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            panel.move();
            panel.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    public int getScreenHeight(){
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight()-125;
        System.out.println(height);
        return height;
    }

    public int getScreenWidth(){
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth()-125;
        System.out.println(width);
        return width;
    }
}
```

**Selector Class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class Selector {
    private BufferedImage img4 = null;
    private Main k;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private BufferedImage img = null;



    private boolean isClicked = false;
    private boolean isPressed = false;
    private Warehouse w;
    private Nose n;

    public Selector (Main k, Warehouse w) {

    this.k = k;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("res\\sizetable.jpg"));
        img4 = ImageIO.read(new File("res\\nose1.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            isClicked = true;
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            isClicked = false;

        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            isPressed = true;
        }
    }


    public void paint (Graphics g) {

        //g.drawImage(img, 230,50,150,150,null);
        //g.setColor(Color.red);
        //g.drawRect(235, 55, 140, 43);
        //g.drawRect(235, 103, 140, 43);
        //g.drawRect(235, 151, 140, 43);
        int num = 0;
        boolean small = false;

        if (isClicked == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 252 && y > 22) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(15, 22, 200, 230);
        }

        if (isPressed == true && x < 375 && x > 235 && y < 98 && y > 55) {
            small = true;
        }
//small
        if (isClicked == true && x < 375 && x > 235 && y < 98 && y > 55) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(235, 55, 140, 43);

        }

        if (small == true && x < 375 && x > 235 && y < 98 && y > 55) {
            g.drawImage(img4, 600, 300, 500, 500, null);

        }
//medium
        if (isClicked == true && x < 375 && x > 235 && y < 146 && y > 103) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(235, 103, 140, 43);
        }
//large
        if (isClicked == true && x < 375 && x > 235 && y < 194 && y > 151) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(235, 151, 140, 43);
        }



        if (isClicked == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y > 272 && y < 502) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(15, 272, 200, 230);
        }

        if (isPressed == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y > 272 && y < 502) {
            g.drawImage(img, 230,300,150,150,null);
        }


        if (isClicked == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 753 && y > 522) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(15, 522, 200, 230);
        }

        if (isPressed == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 753 && y > 522) {
            g.drawImage(img, 230,550,150,150,null);
        }

        if (isClicked == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 1005 && y > 775) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(15, 775, 200, 230);
        }

        if (isPressed == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 1005 && y > 775) {
            g.drawImage(img, 230,800,150,150,null);
        }

if (isPressed == true && x < 215 && x > 15 && y < 252 && y > 22){
    num = 1;
}

if (num == 1){
    g.drawImage(img, 230,50,150,150,null);
}

    }

    public boolean isClicked(){
        return isClicked;
    }

}
```

My teacher told me to draw an instance of it and draw it in main so it stays but I can't figure it out.
The small, medium and large are three different parts the user can pick (rocket part). After they click on the rocket nose image, a menu pops up that mentions small, medium and large. The user is then supposed to click on their desired size and the nose image should paint itself in the middle of the screen. The different sizes don't affect the appearance of the nose itself but the stats of the rocket. So bigger nose = more weight.

Creating new variables, drawing an instance.
One problem I ran into was creating instances. I would have to call in main with the other classes in the parameters but it didn't work since the instance variable in main had to be declared before the instance line.